# Constructing an Object with a Newly-Constructed Array of Newly-Constructed Objects

Tags: java, android, constructor, null, adt

Alright, so I have the following code:

```
Foo f = new Foo (
  new Bar[] {
    new Bar(),
    new Bar(),
    new Bar()
  }, new Bar()
};
```

Constructor for `Foo`:

```
Bar[] barArr = new Bar[];
Bar barLoc;
Foo(Bar[] arr, Bar b)
{
  barArr = arr;
  barLoc = b;
}
```

Constructor for `Bar`:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 7;
int z = 0;
Bar () {  }
```

Which, as I understand it, should be perfectly fine and self-explanatory. However, after the `Bar[]` constructor is finished, my debugger tells me that `Bar[]` contains only `null` objects. Using breakpoints, outputs, etc., I've followed the program through the constructors and confirmed that `Bar()` works perfectly fine, which is supported by how calls to `Bar()` elsewhere in the program behave as expected. I've also confirmed the same for `Foo(Bar[], Obj)` using already-constructed `Bar()` objects.

I would like to avoid doing such if at all possible, as I need to construct >30 of these things, most of which needing unique sets of arguments for each of the constructors - using named variables for each of these would be a readability nightmare.

Of possible importance to note, I am constructing these objects directly within a class (don't recall the specific term for this), rather than within a method.

This leads me to suspect that I am misunderstanding how this sort of thing works in Java (I'm more used to C++, you see). Could someone shine some light on the issue?

I am using ADT and developing for Android 4.3.

Comment: can you show a [complete example that reproduces the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The array you construct in your example does ***not*** contain null entries so the issue is somewhere else...

Comment: Maybe you are shadowing your instance variables in your constructor...

Comment: @assylias That is a complete example that reproduces the issue, with the exception of the constructors for `Foo()` and `Bar()`, the former of which creates a local copy of `Bar[]` and `Bar()`, and the latter of which doing nothing.

Comment: @ZouZou I do not understand what you mean by "shadowing your instance variables"

Comment: @Invictus not really - a complete example would include the `Foo` constructor(s) and relevant fields. That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: You don't have sufficient information (code-wise) to diagnose the problem. e.g. when you say - *my debugger tells me that `Bar[]` contains only null objects*, we don't know which `Bar[]` you are talking about.

Comment: @BheshGurung Er, there is only one Bar[] - the one in the constructor of `Foo`.

Comment: Where in your `Foo` constructor did you put the breakpoint and which of the array variable says everything is null?

Comment: @BheshGurung I put it directly after the end of the `Foo` constructor in the first snippet.

Comment: You should put the breakpoint at `barLoc = b;`, within the `Foo` constructor. And then inspect the variables `barArr` and `arr`. You probably were trying to inspect a non existing variable.

Comment: @BheshGurung At that point in the program, `barLoc` and `barArr` both contain the expected values. it is only when I put the breakpoint directly after the last closing brace in the first snippet that the variables show as being null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal but complete example based on the information you have provided (I have fixed the syntax errors) that shows that the array has non null elements. So your problem is in other parts of your code that you have not shown so far.

It prints `package.name.Test$Bar@15db9742`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Foo f = new Foo(
            new Bar[]{
                new Bar(),
                new Bar(),
                new Bar()
            }, new Bar());
    System.out.println(f.barArr[0]);
}

static class Bar {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 7;
    int z = 0;
}

static class Foo {
    Bar[] barArr;
    Bar barLoc;

    Foo(Bar[] arr, Bar b) {
        barArr = arr;
        barLoc = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a few questions on this: 1. I gather that it makes no difference whether `f` is constructed inside of a method or simply inside a class, then? 2. Why did you make the classes static? 3. I thought that in Java, one had to implement default constructors, rather than leaving that to the compiler - is this not the case?

Comment: (1) no it shouldn't make a difference (to the value of `f.barArr` - it does make a difference in terms of scope of course) (2) because I placed them all in my Test class. I could have made them non-static top level classes too. (3) `public Bar() {}` is equivalent to no constructor at all -  if you don't need to do anything special in the constructor then you don't need one.

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately, I am more confused than ever because that works yet my original code does not. I removed some parts that should not - and did not - have any effect on the error occurring, so I suppose I will now need to look at those again. I've no idea what parts of those could possibly have been relevant. Should I post/link to my original code in the question?

Comment: @Invictus It is difficult to say much more based on the information you have given so far. You could try to use the methodology describe in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to create a complete example that reproduces your issue and post that.